# Should I invest in 401(k) both pre and after tax?

Tags: united-states, 401k

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recent graduate with new job: Choose Roth 401(k), or traditional 401(k)?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/recent-graduate-with-new-job-choose-roth-401k-or-traditional-401k)

My employer offers both pre and after tax 401(k). Since I am in my mid 20s and I don't know what my tax bracket will be when I retire, I was thinking it would be a good compromise to invest 50% of my monthly contributions in pre-tax 401(k) and the other half in after-tax 401(k).

What do you experts think? Is it a good tradeoff?

Comment: When you write "after-tax 401(k)" do you mean "Roth 401(k)" or simply after tax deposits into a 401(k) without the Roth benefits?

Comment: @littleadv - agreed. Identical.

Comment: I think it is a duplicate too.  A good question though. Dave C, If this gets closed as a duplicate that isn't a mark against you.  Having duplicates questions is okay, but we don't need duplicate answers.